# Subsection not showing in Beamer

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am new to Beamer and I've been experimenting with these line of codes but I have an issue with the subsection not displaying when I run the code but what appears to happen is that this line of code is being skipped and I am having a hard time trying to figure why.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}     %I am using metropolis theme
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Definition}
....
....
....
\end{frame}

\subsection{Motivation}

\begin{frame}{The Proof}
...
...
...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Could there be something missing?

I expect something like:

[image]

Comment: You should add `\metroset{subsectionpage=progressbar}`

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \metroset{subsectionpage=progressbar}, see comments.